# MySQL update same table field from DENSE_RANK() results

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, window-functions, dense-rank

i am trying to update field rank using DENSE_RANK() from same table,while trying to execute below query getting "Operand should contain 1 column(s)",kindly help in solving this issue

```
UPDATE scoretable SET rank= (SELECT *,DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY game_id ORDER BY points DESC , diff ASC) FROM scoretable WHERE STATUS ='Active')
```

Table details

[image]

**DENSE_RANK() query results**

```
SELECT *,DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY game_id ORDER BY points DESC , diff ASC) FROM scoretable WHERE STATUS ='Active'
```

[image]

Comment: The immediate error cause is SELECT * but the approach is wrong , consider using the sub query as a join to scoretable on game and user.

Comment: can you help me with query, i have tried with "Update
  scoretable as C
  inner join (SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY game_id ORDER BY points DESC , diff ASC) as result FROM scoretable  WHERE STATUS ='Active' )as A set C.Rank = A.result, "getting 0 rows affected. (Query took 0.0003 seconds.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As commentedby P.Salmon: MySQL does not allow the updated table to appear in a subquery. Instead, you can `dense_rank()` in a subquery, and then `join` it with the table, like so:

```
update scoretable s
inner join (
    select id, dense_rank() over(partition by game_id order by points desc, diff) rn
    from scoretable
    where status = 'Active'
) r on r.id = s.id
set s.rank = r.rn
```

Note: this assumes that `id` is a unique key in the table.